# Add modifier key to scroll a tab page

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Is it possible to add a modifier key (such as `Ctrl`) to the mouse wheel scroll on a `tabPage`?

**EDIT :**

Because I have controls on the `tabPage` that requires the use of the mouse wheel, I'd like to add a modifier key to the mouse wheel scroll on the `tabPage`. This way, the user will be able to play with the controls with the mouse wheel and will be able to scroll down or up the `tabPage` by using `Ctrl` + the mouse wheel.

Comment: Then you have to override the behavior of the wheel scroll on the tab page and check if Ctrl is pressed, then change the behavior.

Comment: @Jeff I have controls on my `tabPage` that requires the use of the mouse wheel.

Comment: @MrFox Do I need to create a new tabPage class in order to override the mouse wheel behavior?

Comment: Ah I misread what you're doing here.  I saw it as "Add modifier key to a tab page."  So you want to make a scrollable tab page?  Instead of doing that, I'd suggest reconsidering your design.

Comment: @Jeff No. I already have a scrollable `tabPage` (`AutoScroll` property = `true`). What I want is the `tabPage` to not scroll when the user is playing with his mouse wheel.

Comment: @Leito: I see that but I'm suggesting that you don't make it scrollable and find another way to design it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is inherit from TabPage and handle the WM_MOUSEWHEEL event:

```
public class MyTabPageHandlingCTRL : System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
{
    const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {

        if (m.HWnd != this.Handle)
            return;
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && 
            (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != Keys.Control)
        {
            return; // don't propagate the event
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Of course in your `TabControl.TabPages` you must add `MyTabPageHandlingCTRL` instead of the simple `TabPage`.

Answer (score 0):

are you intend to detect when mouse scrolling and with ctrl being hold, you wanna treat them as tab changing?

create the 3 events handling for the mouse-scrolling and keydown, keyup event.
on a flag when the ctrl is down. negate the flag when that key is up
when mouse-scrolling event kick-in detect if the flag is on, then do your trick.

Comment: Not tab changing but tab scrolling.

Comment: so what's your problem? are you trying to figure out how to work out the scrolling trick or detect the key+mouse events?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the `tabPage` to scroll when the user is playing with his mouse wheel, cause I need the mouse wheel to be used on other controls.